# Convexity of a (non-symmetric) function of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f : H_{n\times n} (\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function on Hermitian, positive semidefinite matrices $f(A) = \frac{M_i (A)}{\det(A)}$ where $M_i(A)$ is the determinant of the the submatrix formed by the $A_{kl}$ where $1\leq k, l \leq i$, i.e., it is the $i\times i$ principal minor of $A$.
Is the function $f$ convex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Theorem 9, of this article](http://www-isl.stanford.edu/~cover/papers/paper86.pdf) it follows that $A \mapsto \log\frac{M_i(A)}{\det(A)}$ is convex on the set of positive definite matrices. The alleged convexity in the OP is a simple consequence of this stronger log-convexity result.

Comment: More easily, this also follows from Jacobi's identity: $\det(A[S]) = \det(A)\det(A^{-1}[\bar{S}]$, where $A[S]$ is the principal submatrix index by $S$, which $\bar{S}$ denotes the complement of $S$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is No.

If you consider only diagonal matrices then the question is equivalent to   whether the function $B(x_{1},\ldots, x_{n})=\prod_{j=1}^{m}x_{j}^{-1}$ is convex function over $\mathbb{R}^{m}$  (for $1 \leq m \leq n-1$).

For example the function  $B(x,y)=\frac{1}{xy}$ is concave function in the domain $x \geq 0 $ and $y \leq 0$.

However, the function $f$ might be convex for positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add the assumption of semidefiniteness.